# Caching posts using redis

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, load-balancing, node-cluster

I have a forum which contains groups, new groups are created all the time by users, currently I'm using node-cache with ttl to cache groups and it's content (posts, likes and comments).

The server worked great at the begging but the performance decreased when more people start using the app, so I decided to use the node.js Cluster module as the next step to improve performance.

The node-cache will cause a consistency problem, the same group could be cached in two workers, so if one of them changed, the other will not know (unless you do).

The first solution that came to my mind is using redis to store the whole group and it's content with the help of redis datatypes (sets and hash objects), but I don't know how efficient this could be.

The other solution is using redis to map requests to the correct worker, in this case the cached data is distributed randomly in workers, so when a worker receives a request that related to some group, he checks the group owner(the worker that holds this group instance in-memory) in redis and ask him to get the wanted data using node-ipc and then return it to the user.

Is there any problem with the first solution? 
The second solution does not provides a fairness (if all the popular groups landed in the same worker), is there a solution for this?

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance